# Return statement not satisfying generic return type despite the constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

So I have this method that returns a generic type; this method is required by the interface. The generic type TOutput is constrained to be a List. Despite my return value being a List, it still will not compile. Error is only at the return statement (cannot convert to TOuput). Any ideas?

```
public class QueryCollectionDataSourceBase<TInput, TOutputType, TOutput> : IQueryCollectionDataSource<TInput, TOutputType, TOutput>
    where TOutput : List<TOutputType>
{
    public virtual Func<TInput, SqlParameter[]> ParameterAdapter { get; private set; }
    public virtual Func<IDataRecord, TOutputType> ObjectAdapter { get; private set; }

    protected QueryCollectionDataSourceBase(Func<TInput, SqlParameter[]> parameterAdapter,
                                  Func<IDataRecord, TOutputType> objectAdapter)
    {
        ParameterAdapter = parameterAdapter;    
        ObjectAdapter = objectAdapter;
    }   

    public TOutput Execute(TInput request)
    {
        using (var rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(
            DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString,
            CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
            "dbo.usp_ws_act_UserByAccountIDGet", 
            ParameterAdapter(request)))
        {
            var result = new List<TOutputType>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(ObjectAdapter(rdr));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

public interface IQueryCollectionDataSource<in TRequest, out TListType, out TOutput> : IQueryDataSource<TRequest, TOutput>
    where TOutput : List<TListType>
{
    Func<IDataRecord, TListType> ObjectAdapter { get; }
}
```

Comment: Why should `TOutput` be its own class? Do you expect to have _subclasses_ of `List<TListType>`? Is it possible to change the signature to dump `TOutput` entirely and just have the methods return an `IEnumerable<TListType>`?

Comment: I actually tried IEnumerable originally with the same result

Answer (score 0):

`Execute` is supposed to return a `TOutput` but instead it's returning a `List`  of `TOutputType`. A `TOutput` is constrained to be a `List<TOutputType>` but a `List<TOutputType>` isn't constrained to be a `TOutput`.

Try instantiating `result` as:

```
var result = new TOutput();
```

and see how that goes.

Comment: I think your diagnosis is correct. But the problem with this is that `TOutput` isn't defined with the `new()` constraint so you wouldn't be able to instantiate it this way. (Would either have to use reflection or a slight change of design)